# What does userInteractionEnabled = NO mean and how does it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Cocos 2d-iphone 3.0. I am using this code to detect whether a single sprite is touched

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
    CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];
    
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_sprite boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint)) 
    {
        // Remove sprite 
    }
}
```

I have some code inside that should remove some other sprites from parent. Logically, when `_sprite`

is touched second time, application will crash, because other sprites'v been already removed.

I was trying to make `_sprite` untouchable using  `_sprite.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`, but this has no effect.

What does `userInteractionEnabled` mean exactly and how would one use this to facilitate touch detection on sprites.

What is the optimal way of handling touches on sprites in my scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable interactions on a ccsprite. What you should do is:

```
bool firstTimeClicked=false;

-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(firstTimeClicked==true)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
    CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_sprite boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint)) {
        firstTimeClicked=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode says that this void should not return a value. I changed 'return NO' to 'return'. Works great!

Comment: Yes, you can disable user interactions on a sprite. That means that the `touchBegan` for example will not be called. You are using the position of the touch in the screen to detect sprites under that touch. This is not the best way to do it. Then you are using this ugly workaround for something that works, and you are returning a BOOL value from a void method. This is the worst way you could do this.

Comment: Small note - there's usually no need to compare a boolean value with `true` or `false` explicitly. Instead, doing `if(firstTimeClicked)` (or, for the opposite case, `if(!firstTimeClicked)` achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

### What userInteractionEnabled does

When you set `userInteractionEnabled=YES` on a sprite that mean that user interaction callbacks are going to get called.

So for example in your scene if you would have `userInteractionEnabled=NO` your `-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` would not get called.

### What you we're doing

You were detecting the touches in your scene. And then you we're checking what was under that touch location, so if anything was under there it would be detected.

### How to accomplish this properly - subclass your CCSprite

You want to handle these kind of behaviours in custom `CCSprite` classes, because if not your scenes `touchBegan` is going to turn into a **huge buggy** `if else switch` statement.

Believe me, I have been there.

Here is a code example of what this class could look like :

The **.h** file

```
@interface SubclassedSprite : CCSprite

@end
```

And the **.m** file

```
@implementation SubclassedSprite

- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"Touch began on sprite");
    // Your code when the Sprite was touched [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}

@end
```

This is the **proper, scalable** way to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

Below code is without taking an extra BOOL variable and it should work for you:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:                   location];
    CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self  convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_sprite  boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint)) {
      if(_sprite.userInteractionEnabled)//Here you can remove the children of _sprite. e.g.
         {
          //Here run some action or do what you want to do. For e.g.
          CCFadeTo *fadeOut = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5f opacity:0];
          CCCallfuncN *clean = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self SEL:@selector(cleanSpriteChildren:)];
          for(id item in _sprite.children)
             if(item)
               [item runAction:[CCSequence runActions:fadeOut, clean]];
         }
         else{//Do your own task while _sprite is untouchable} 
    } 
  }

  -(void)cleanSpriteChildren:(id)sender
     {         
        [item removeFromParentAndCleanUp:YES]
        if(([_sprite children] count) == 0)
           _sprite.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //Here make the _sprite touchable again
     }
```

Comment: ,my real code looks similar. Just without  'if(_sprite.userInteractionEnabled)'. It's enabled by default('self.userInteractionEnabled'). Only   '_sprite.userInteractionEnabled = NO;' doesn't work.
Or is that condition 'if(_sprite.userInteractionEnabled)'necessary to make '_sprite.userInteractionEnabled = NO;' work right?

Comment: _sprite.userInteractionEnabled is by default enabled at the beginning. And when user touches the sprite it will execute if(_sprite.userInteractionEnabled){...} only for once (or as long userInteractionEnabled is re-enabled back). So in this above snippet after it gets set to NO, next time when user touches the sprite it will come to else{} block. So you are not going to remove any children of _sprite which were already removed. So there will not eb a crash. So conclusion is the if(_sprite.userInteractionEnabled){} is required in your case.

Comment: OK, after I edited in your way, sprite is untouchable at all. Theoretically all actions that come together with making sprite untouchable should be implemented the same(and cannot be implemented again). But in fact sprite becomes untouchable and all actions that should be implemented only once when sprite is touched are not implemented. Must I make a sequence or another one void method for making sprite untouchable after all actions inside are done ? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to delete '_sprite.userInteractionEnabled=NO' and sprite was still untouchable. Something wrong with if condition

Comment: I am not yet sure what you want to achieve. What i understood is on first touch you want to run some CCAction and then remove all the children of _sprite. And then make the _sprite again touchable. is this what you want? If so I edited my answer again. Try this. If not let me know.